# How to get stdout from a child process OF a child process as it runs?

Tags: python, docker, stdout

I'm running a python script that triggers a script inside a docker container, which prints out its start time, starts another process with arguments, and then prints out its end time, after the process it triggered is done.

I've been using this code to trigger the script in the container and get its output:

```
pr = subprocess.Popen('docker exec ' + docker_container + ' /scripts/sct.sh', cwd=os.path.dirname('/'),
                                                shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
        if debug:
                while True:
                        output = pr.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
                        if output == '' and pr.poll() is not None:
                                break
                        if output:
                                print(output.strip())
        else:
                (out, error) = pr.communicate()
                print("### re-index: error message: " + error.decode('utf-8'))
                print("### re-index: message: " + out.decode('utf-8'))
```

When I run in debug mode I want to be able to see all of the output lines from the process triggered by the script inside the container, as it runs, so I could see if it hangs, stop it running, adjust its settings, and rerun to see if I solved thing.

Problem is, when I try it, I only get the start time line from the script inside the container, on the fly. The rest of the lines (the output from the process the script inside the container triggered) only come through after the process the script inside the container triggered is done running.

The process takes hours, whether it works well or badly, so just waiting for it to finish and then analyzing the results is not an option.

Is there any way I could adjust my code to get the output of BOTH my child process (= the script inside the container) and *its* child process (=the process it triggers) as they run, and not after the child's child process ends?

Other than cutting out the middleman and triggering the child's child's process directly, that is, which I really would like to avoid.

Comment: Not that it really addresses your question, but why not use the `time` utility?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to know how long the process took. When the process the script inside the container triggers finishes running and I get all of its output lines, it also includes a full report on how long it took to run and how long every single part of it took to run, too. See, I'm still setting it up, so I want to know BEFORE it ends if I did it ok, and we're talking about hours, here, whether it works fine or not, so, better to find out early if something stalled it, so I can adjust and rerun. That's why I want the output on the fly.

Comment: Okay, that's valuable context info. You might want to [edit] your question to include that directly and avoid the misunderstanding I fell for. Oh, one more thing: Do you know if the behaviour specific to `docker exec`? What if you just exec a shellscript that outputs things with pauses in between?

Comment: If I can specify `docker_container` I can trivially use this command to root the entire system.  I'd suggest not using `docker exec` to interact with containers, but instead accessing them through network I/O.  If you can't do that, you must not use `shell=True` and especially not with a dynamically constructed string.

Comment: @DavidMaze I can't specify the container in advance. I'll see if I can drop the shell=True. Thanks for the advice. It's an enclosed system, but security is always best.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the edit suggestion. I added it. As to the docker exec versus just a process... that's a really good question. I'll try it out! Still, I think it's not the issue. I mean, if it were, wouldn't it have prevented me from seeing the start time line as well?

Comment: How much output do these processes produce? Is it possible that the output is stuck in some of the pipe's buffer? Do you have enough control over the system to reduce the pipe buffer size? Or explicitly add calls to `flush`? To figure out where exactly things are stuck (pipe from child process to your script or between your script and docker) you could output (with appropriate flushing) to a file instead and check that file.

Comment: @DanielJunglas Well, over the course of the whole run, the process can output quite a bit.  However, when it starts out, it's more like - "one line and then wait ten minutes... another line and then wait ten minutes". And it's not that it's outputting some lines from it and then stopping. It's just not outputting anything from it, from the moment it starts till it's done running. The only line I get is the one outputted by the script that triggers the process, and then it's a wait till the process is done.

Comment: Given that you get the output but only in a delayed fashion, I think it is clear that something is stuck in some buffer. My best idea to debug this is to use `flush` as much as possible and redirect output through files.

Comment: @DanielJunglas Added flush=True to all output and redirected output to file. Same result. :(